# How do you create a Radar chart using chart.js with a y-axis of 0 to 100?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am currently using Chart.js to display my data as a radar chart.  The problem I am facing is that each time I add data to the page, it sets the max value to whatever the highest value is in the table.  I need it to start with a Y-axis of 0 to 100.

I am using Chart.js v 2.1.2

Here's the chart and config code for the chart:

```
myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);

var config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: radarChartData,

  options:
      {
          responsive: false,
          maintainAspectRadio: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            },
          title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Radar Chart'
              },
          scale: {
              reverse: false,
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  },
              pointLabels: {
                  callback: function (pointLabel) {
                      if (pointLabel.length > 10)
                      return pointLabel.substring(0, 10) + '...';
                      else
                      return pointLabel
                      }
                  }

           },
           scaleOverride: true,
           scaleSteps: 5,
           scaleStepWidth: 20,
           scaleStartValue: 100,
           }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this on 2.2.1, no sure if they had Min/Max for your version.

```
ticks: {
   max:100, // Set it to your Max value
   min: 0, // You can also change the Min
   beginAtZero: false, // in case you change the Min
}, // etc
```

Docs: [tick configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#ticks-configuration) 
Codepen: [Chart.js Radar Chart](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/ozQEkd?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling there had to be an easy response to this. I'll see if it works with my version or just upgrade it and make sure it doesn't fall over.